# Macro assigned to inserted button does not run when inserted button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA to insert a button:

```
Sub Insert_Button()
    Dim Button_01 As Button
    Set Button_01 = Sheet1.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15)
    Set Range_Button_01 = Sheet1.Range("B1:C5")
    Button_01.Name = "Button_01"
    With Button_01
    .Top = Range_Button_01.Top
    .Left = Range_Button_01.Left
    .Width = Range_Button_01.Width
    .Height = Range_Button_01.Height
    .Text = "Button_01"
    .OnAction = "Insert_Values"
    End With
End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

As you can see I have assigned a VBA `.onAction` to the button:

```
Sub Insert_Values()
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 200
End Sub
```

Once the button is inserted and I click on it I get the following error message:

```
This macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled
```

So far I have tried to change the `.OnAction` property like this:

```
.OnAction = ActiveSheet.Name & ".Insert_Values"
.OnAction ="ThisWorkbook.Insert_Values"
```

However, I could not make it work. 
What do I need to change in my code so the assigned macro runs without any issue?

Comment: Your code works. The only Error I saw was that you were missing `Dim Range_Button_01 As Range`

Comment: Where is the `Insert_Values` procedure defined? Consider renaming it to `InsertValues`, since the underscore has a special meaning in VBA (not that it changes anything, just... it *may* eventually bite you)

Comment: It is defined in "ThisWorkbook"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is defined in "ThisWorkbook"

Add a new standard module, move the macro procedure there.

`ThisWorkbook` is an object: its public members can't be invoked without a qualifier. By moving the code to a standard module, the public procedure becomes accessible everywhere without a qualifier.

Alternatively, you could qualify the member call. If I manually assign a macro to a public procedure in `ThisWorkbook` and then output the shape's `OnAction` property value, I get this:

```
Book1!ThisWorkbook.Test
```

So, you were close! This should work, assuming no whitespaces involved:

```
.OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!ThisWorkbook.Insert_Values"
```

If `ThisWorkbook.Name` has spaces, you'll want to enclose it in single quotes (untested):

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!ThisWorkbook.Insert_Values"
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks a lot for answer. I guess based on this I would have to move a lot of code from "This Workbook" into the module in my original file since the orignal code is much more complex then just Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 200.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the alternative solutions and your thoughts. They actually work well. The only issue I see is that they are not internationally. Since I am using a German Excel I have to go with "'!DieseArbeitsmappe.Insert_Values". so if another co-worker with an English Excel wants to run the Macro it probably will not work for him.

Comment: @Michi Yikes! That's the "fun" of *stringly-typed* code... if you need to address that concern then you'll need to authorize programmatic access to the VBIDE API, and concatenate `Thisworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(1).Name` instead of `"ThisWorkbook"` (assuming the first component of any VBA project hosted in Excel is the host `Workbook` document module)

Comment: @Michi actually - it shouldn't be a problem at all - if the VBComponent name is `DieseArbeitsmappe`, that *should* be preserved when the workbook is opened in an other-language Excel instance. Otherwise every single `DieseArbeitsmappe.Worksheets` call would just stop compiling!